# What is the reason for this long frame

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, css-transitions, css-animations, performance-testing

I'm analyzing a long frame (70ms) in my animation, but given the devtools info, I can't understand the reason. Here's what I get:

[image]

The numbers don't add up. The frame length is 70ms, while summing the individual frame drawing calls yields around 8ms.

---

I tried enabling experimental features:

[image]

I still get strange void:

[image]

Comment: Timeline doesn't show internal V8 time by default. You can enable devtools experiments in chrome://flags, restart, open devtools, it's settings, then experiments, press the Shift key 6 times, enable the timeline-related checkboxes for V8 runtime, all events, etc.

Comment: @wOxxOm question updated